# Не работает font-face

Tags: html, css

Вопрос уже много раз тут звучал, но ответы никакие не помогают , обычно я использую отдельный css файл, в котором прописываю font-face, путь к шрифту

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'Century';
  src: url('../font/centurygothic/CenturyGothic.eot');
  src: url('../font/centurygothic/CenturyGothic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../font/centurygothic/CenturyGothic.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('../font/centurygothic/CenturyGothic.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('../font/centurygothic/CenturyGothic.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal; 
  font-style: normal; 
}
```

Использую даже не какой то кастомный шрифт, а обычный , который есть в винде, сначала даже не было необходимости подключать его отдельно, так как все и так работало, но как оказалось на телефоне шрифт не отображается , решил подключить отдельно и вообще никак не работает , я уже много разных шрифтов подключал и никаких не было проблем, пол дня просидел , много форумов прочитал , сделал в разных форматах , подключал в самом начале основного css файла , не работает .

**Решено , была простая опечатка которую не видел , указал неправильно путь**

Comment: Не отображается как кириллица так и латиница? Откуда брали шрифт? как создавали web-форматы?

Comment: не работает кириллица и латиница , брал с двух сайтов , был вариант что битый шрифт  (allshrift.ru , fonts4web.ru) конвертировал в двух сервисах - первый (всегда им пользовался) https://onlinefontconverter.com/ , так же нашел потом еще один - https://www.web-font-generator.com/ , пробовал , не работает

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ошибку , оказалось неправильно был указан путь

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/229362)

Comment: @IgorLavrynenko, вроде является. Но вопрос я закрыл как опечатку.